# jQuery - A function to scale multiple divs in proportion to window height

Tags: jquery, css, function, html, scale

Please help a noob out.

I am trying to create a jQuery function that will rescale and reposition multiple absolute positioned divs in proportion to window height.

I have included the following code to illustrate the kind of result I am trying to achieve.
The number 960 represents the maximum height in pixels that any div on the page will have. So when resized, 960 should equal 100% of the window height.

For the variables: divHeight, divLeft and divTop I have entered their values manually because I don't know how to retrieve their values from the css and then restore these original values when the window is resized so that the function is not calculating the div height and position based on the new values.

```
function scaleDivs() {
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var divHeight = 348;
    var divLeft = 40;
    var divTop = 100;
    var percentDif = (winHeight / 960) * 100;
    var newHeight = (percentDif / 100) * divHeight;
    newHeight = parseInt(newHeight) + "px";
    var newLeft = (percentDif / 100) * divLeft;
    newLeft = parseInt(newLeft) + "px";
    var newTop = (percentDif / 100) * divTop;
    newTop = parseInt(newTop) + "px";
    $("#panel_0").css({"height": newHeight, "left": newLeft, "top": newTop});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    scaleDivs();
    $(window).bind('resize', scaleDivs);
});
```

What I'd like to have is one function to control multiple divs - getting the required css values automatically.

If anyone knows of a plugin that does what I'm asking or if you could point out what I need to change in my code to make what I'm asking possible I would greatly appreciate it.

---

**... Edit ...**

This solution uses **.data** to to retrieve the initial values of the divs height and position.

***jQuery***

```
function scalePanels() {
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var ratio960 = winHeight / 960;
    $(".panelCont").each(function(){
        var panelHeight = $(this).data("initial-height");
        var newHeight = panelHeight * ratio960;
        newHeight = parseInt(newHeight) + "px";
        var panelTop = $(this).data("initial-top");
        var newTop = panelTop * ratio960;
        newTop = parseInt(newTop) + "px";
        var panelLeft = $(this).data("initial-left");
        var newLeft = panelLeft * ratio960;
        newLeft = parseInt(newLeft) + "px";
        $(this).css({"height": newHeight, "top": newTop, "left": newLeft});
    });

};

$(document).ready(function() {
  scalePanels();
  $(window).bind('resize', scalePanels);
});
```

***html***

```
<div class="group_1">
  <div class="panelCont" id="pnl_0a"
    data-initial-height= "960"
    data-initial-left= "0"
    data-initial-top= "0">
    <img src="images/pnl_0a.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="panelCont" id="pnl_0_title"
    data-initial-height= "97"
    data-initial-left= "186"
    data-initial-top= "26">
    <img src="images/pnl_0_title.svg" />
  </div>
  <div class="panelCont" id="pnl_0b"
    data-initial-height= "960"
    data-initial-left= "0"
    data-initial-top= "0">
    <img src="images/pnl_0b.jpg" />
  </div>  
</div>
```

***css***

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#pnl_0a {
    margin: 0px;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
#pnl_0_title {
    margin: 0px;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
}
#pnl_0b {
    margin: 0px;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}
img {
    margin: 0px;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
object {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution involves using percentages instead of px to set both position and height. This way you use only CSS no javascript at all.

```
#panel_0 {
    height: 36%;
    left: 7%;
    top: 11%;
}
```

this solution may be problematic if you aren't using only percentages for location (see also [this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions) article about flexible positioning)

if you want javascript anyway you can try something like this (untested though, so beware):

```
function adjust(wrapper){
    var wrapperHeight = $(wrapper).height();  
    var wrapperWidth = $(wrapper).width();
    var elementArr = [];

    // create location index for all the elements inside the wrapper 
    $.each($(wrapper).children('.adjustable'),function(key,value){
        var percLeft = $(value).css('left')/wrapperWidth;
        var percTop = $(value).css('top')/wrapperHeight; 
        var percHeight = $(value).height()/wrapperHeight;

        var elem = [value,percLeft,percTop,percHeight];
        elementArr.push(elem);
    });

    $(document).resize(function(){          
        $.each(elementArr, function(key,value){
            $(value[0])
                .css('left', $(value[0]).css('left') * value[1])
                .css('top',$(value[0]).css('top') * value[2])
                .height($(value[0]).height() * value[3]);           
        });
    }); 
};
```

Comment: I had considered using percentages but it would mean that I'd have to know the full width of the document beforehand. If I altered the document width I would have to recalculate the percentages. I thought it would be neater from a design point of view if I could use pixel values instead. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: added an alternative, hope it helps :)